# Cross-national data on lending interest rate for the whole world from 2006-2019

Tags: data-request

I am looking for a cross-national dataset on yearly average (lending) interest rates. I know the World Bank features an [indicator](https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/FR.INR.LEND), but surprising to me the indicator has missing data for lots of countries in Europe. I am also open to augment the World Bank indicator with a indicator from another data source if they are comparable.